# Why structured bindings only work with auto

Tags: c++, c++17, auto, structured-bindings

[Structured bindings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) have been introduced with c++17. They give the ability to declare multiple variables initialised from a tuple or struct.

This code compiles using a `c++17` compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(1.0, 1);

    auto [ d, i ] = tuple;

    std::cout << "d=" << d << " i=" << i <<  '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

If I don't declare the variables with `auto` I get the error

**error: expected body of lambda expression**
    [d2 , i2] = tuple;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(1.0, 2);

    double d2;
    int i2;

    [d2 , i2] = tuple;

    return 0;
}
```

I used `clang version 4.0.0` and the compile option `-std=c++1z`.

Can I assign existing variables to a structured binding? Do I need to use `auto`?

Comment: Structured binding is only possible when defining and initializing variables. It's not possible as a general assignment (for that use [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error message your got is pretty indicative of why it's only allowed with `auto`: lack of ambiguity that will make the grammar *even more* context dependent.

A pair of square brackets at the start of an expression indicates a lambda. What you are asking is for the standard to specify that *sometimes* `[d2 , i2]` is the beginning of a lambda that captures `d2` and `i2` by value, and at *other times* it's an unpacking assignment. All based on what follows it.

It's just not worth the complexity to add it to the language. Especially, since [as Some programmer dude noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764614/why-structured-bindings-only-work-with-auto/46764763#comment80474489_46764614), you already have `std::tie` to do what you want with tuples.

Not only that, `std::tie` allows you to ignore some of the unpacked values, something structured bindings don't support yet. So it all boils down to having a more limited form of syntactic sugar, to do something the standard library already does with tuples.

---

Oh, and if you are disgruntles that `std::tie` works only with tuples, you can expand it to work with any POD yourself. Just look at this [`magic_get` implementation](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get). One can apply the same idea to `constexpr` transform a POD into a tuple of reference that can be fed to `std::tie`. Something like this:

```
std::tie(d2, i2) = magic_unpack(/*some POD that isn't a tuple*/);
```

Comment: I don't think that's at all true. You could just add a keyword before a structured binding if auto is not being used, like so: `structured_binding [d2, i2] = tuple`. Someone else can come up with a syntax that looks nice, but it's the same effort to parse as with `auto`. You could then do this: `strucutured_binding [ bool d2, int i2]`. That's mainly why I would like the feature, because you could use structured bindings with explicit typing and with things that are not default constructible.

Comment: @iPherian - Then you missed the point of the question. It's not why auto is the keyword, but why a keyword is required at all.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Agree on that – Still iPherian met a good point – would be nice e.g. to automatically change signedness or size of integrals. `auto [int n, double d, /* and the defaulting */ x]` would be totally fine for in my eyes, though, no need for *yet another* keyword... Maybe nice, too, being able to combine both values and references: `auto [&r, v]`?

Comment: That's not the reason to not using `std::tuple [d1, i2] = tuple`.

Comment: @TuffContender - No, the reason to not do *that* is that C++ is not pure token soup, but really does divide between keywords and library types. What you just proposed makes no sense in how the language works.

Comment: I found "If I use structured bindings, the types of the bindings are what matters in a strong/concrete API boundary, the whole-object type is irrelevant" in http://wg21.link/p0480r1 , though I'm still a little suspicious of it.

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can using `std::tie()` to unpack the tuple into its individual components. Such as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(1.0, 1);
    double d2;
    int i2;
    std::tie(d2, i2) = tuple;

    std::cout << "d2=" << d2 << " i2=" << i2 <<  '\n';

    return 0;
}
```