# How to initialize a const primitive from a function returning a tuple with explicit type

Tags: c++, constants, stdtuple

I have a function that returns `const` values not by reference as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68937433/return-stdtuple-containing-const-reference-in-c11). I would like to call the function and initialize the `const` variables when I call the function but it isn't possible.

I tried declaring the variables but that is only possible if the variables are not `const`. Is there a way to intialize `const` variables by type after this call?

I tried the `auto` suggestion in [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931883/cannot-initialize-const-int-from-unpacked-tuple), which worked but I am surprised that it didn't work when I used `size_t` explicitly. Why wouldn't it work without `auto`? Isn't the type after using `auto` going to be `size_t` because this is what the function returns? I would like to use the explicit type to make it easier to read.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

std::tuple<const size_t, const size_t> returnSize_T_Tuple() {
    const size_t i = 2;
    const size_t j = 3;

    return {i, j};
}

std::tuple<const int, const int> returnIntTuple() {
    const int i = 2;
    const int j = 3;

    return {i, j};
}

int main(){
    // const size_t s_i; // error: uninitialized ‘const s_i’ [-fpermissive]
    // std::tie(const size_t x, const size_t y) = returnSize_T_Tuple(); // error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
    const auto [x,y] = returnSize_T_Tuple();
    const size_t [a,b] = returnSize_T_Tuple(); // error: structured binding declaration cannot have type ‘const size_t’ {aka ‘const long unsigned int’}

    cout << "x = " << x << "; " << "a = " << a;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work without `auto` because that's how the feature is defined. Structured binding only accepts `auto` type specifiers. You'd need to petition the commitee (and/or compiler developers) to change this feature

Comment: You'd also need to think about what if you tried to unpack a tuple that does not have 2 objects of the same type - then you'd need to invent some more syntax for that as well. That's presumably why only `auto` is allowed

Comment: *"Why wouldn't it work without auto?"* Because that's how the language defined it. See [c++ - Why structured bindings only work with auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764614/why-structured-bindings-only-work-with-auto)

Comment: @UnholySheep, are the variables `size_t` though after the unpacking?

Answer (score 0):

According to [P0217R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0217r3.html) proposed wording for structured bindings:

> The auto type-specifier is also used to introduce a decomposition declaration (8.5 [dcl.decomp]).

So based on that, in this context `auto` isn't really a type specifier, it's just the syntax required for declaring a decomposition expression while being there as "something to stick const and ref-qualifiers onto".